# Create a random apache access log

Tags: apache, logging

To test some programs which process apache access logs, I need access logs of variable length and content. Is there a program or website which creates such log files? (I can't use my own access log files, since they are to small)

Answer (score 1):

there is some here

you can search for other on google
http://www.monitorware.com/en/logsamples/apache.php

Comment: This is very static, I'm looking for a program which I can tell a certain start and end date etc.